# example of a symmetric matrix using sum of diagonals and sum of the squares

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm a bit stuck on this practice example given in an online [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/matrix-algebra-engineers/supplement/1ZPq6/example-of-a-symmetric-matrix) I'm taking

[image]

So I take the transpose of A:
$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f
\end{pmatrix}$
multiplied by A:
$\begin{pmatrix}
a & d\\
b & e\\
c & f
\end{pmatrix}$

Then I get
$\begin{pmatrix}
aa & bb & cc\\
dd & ee & ff
\end{pmatrix}$

Now i get stuck... what does the "**sum of its diagnol elements is the sum of the squares of all the elements of A** look like? $A^TA$ is a rectangular matrix so I'm thinking the diagonals might be $dd~bb$ or $ff~bb$ but this does not seem to make sense.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's not conventional matrix multiplication. I get $$\pmatrix{a^2+b^2+c^2&*\\*&*}$$ where the $*$s are entries I haven't written out.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication for the definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: You don't have the good definition of matrix multiplication (see the link given by @AnginaSeng). Let's also recall that the multiplication of a $(2,3)$-matrix by a $(3,2)$-matrix gives a $(2,2)$-matrix. Finally, if a matrix is rectangular, talking about its diagonal elements has no sense.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! this is super helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say your matrix multiplication is wrong. The multiplication you have should be multiplying 2 columns and 2 rows and so you should be getting a 2x2 matrix. A good rule of thumb to know the dimension of your final matrix would be to look at the dimension of your other matrices. Matrix A is a 3x2 matrix (3 rows and 2 columns) while its transpose is a 2x3 matrix. So a 2x3 matrix multiplying a 3x2 matrix will be a 2x2 matrix. Look at the first dimension (rows) of your first matrix and the last dimension (columns) of your last matrix. That should tell you what your final matrix should look like.

When multiplying 2 matrices, the last dimension of your first matrix and first dimension of your last matrix should be the same. They're both 3, so you are able to multiply these 2 together.

A fun way to learn how to multiply matrices fast would be to imagine you have a fork that stabs your first row of your first matrix. You then lift your first row and multiply it against the first column of your other matrix. This is your FIRST term of your new matrix. You do this with the first row of your first matrix and every column of your  second matrix to create the first row of your final matrix. Repeat until you are done.

Angina Seng's comment captures what I was trying to say about multiplication. So I won't include my picture anymore.

Comment: Thank you @user817965 appreciate the response